# Can probability distribution predict the electricity consumption of the coming months? if no what do you recommend?

Tags: probability, distributions

Can probability distribution predict the electricity consumption of the coming months based on a historical consumption data? can it give me a figure?
If NO or not recommended for such case, what do you recommend if the only data you have is the past consumption of the house in the city?

Comment: Yes, but it will probably be wrong.  Some forecasts turn out to have been better than others thanks to their skill, and some thanks to luck.

Comment: thanks ... but can you please recommend an alternative?

Comment: Going anywhere with this problem will require more details. Please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: I only have the electricity consumption of all the houses in a city per month of the year, since 2005... and I am asked to predict the consumption of new houses based on that :(

Comment: Do you have that per house, or the total? population growth? ...

Comment: yes it is per house per month of the year